# Accessing a JSON key based on a lower level property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the solution, for lacking the appropriate words to describe the issue.

I'm trying to access an object's key (e.g. `"ID1"`), in an object of objects, according to the value of one of its lower keys (e.g. `"name":"name1"`).
The JSON object contains different ID objects, each of which contains a name and other properties.

```
mydata = {
"ID1":    {"name":"name1","akey":true,"anotherkey":"foor"},
"ID2":    {"name":"name2","akey":true,"anotherkey":"bar"},
"ID3":    {"name":"name3","akey":false,"anotherkey":"foo"}
}
```

It's pretty simple to get the `name` if I know the `ID`, e.g.:

```
myname = mydata["ID1"].name;  //returns "name1"
```

But what I'm trying to do is get the `ID` of an object if I know its `name`, so in short, the reverse of the above line. Is there any simple solution for this (in pure Javascript or jQuery)? Note: I know the names are unique.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) can help you.  It would look something like this:

```
var mydata = {
    "ID1": {"name":"name1","akey":true,"anotherkey":"foor"},
    "ID2": {"name":"name2","akey":true,"anotherkey":"bar"},
    "ID3": {"name":"name3","akey":false,"anotherkey":"foo"}
}

Object.keys(mydata).forEach(function(id) {
    var obj = mydata[id];
    if (obj.name === "name1") {
        // I found an object based on the "name" property.
        // the 'id' variable holds a reference to it.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mydata = {
"ID1":    {"name":"name1","akey":true,"anotherkey":"foor"},
"ID2":    {"name":"name2","akey":true,"anotherkey":"bar"},
"ID3":    {"name":"name3","akey":false,"anotherkey":"foo"}
}

var parentId = Object.keys(mydata).find(function(key){
  return mydata[key].name === 'name2';
});

console.log(parentId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it, is to traverse over every property-value.

```
var result = null;
for(var key in mydata) {
  if(mydata[key].name==='name1'){
    result = key;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```